# mysql duplicate subquery in where clause

Tags: mysql, subquery

I need to do selection from mysql 5.7.22 in one query.

```
select id from t1 where type_id=(select type_id from t2 where id=1 limit 1) and id not in  
            (select obj_id from t2
                where 
                    type_id = (select type_id from t2 where id=1 limit 1)
                    and
                    type2_id = (select type2_id from t2 where id=1 limit  
                    ...
             )
```

I have some duplicate subquerys in where clause (it's only part of the query, this subquery duplicates many times)

```
'(select type_id from t2 where id=1 limit 1)'
```

Can I some how figure it out in one place, to reduce verbose.
So I want to select once

```
select type_id, type2_id from t2 where id=1 limit 1
```

and make type_id, type2_id available in all query context.

I know mysql 8.0 has WITH syntax, but I am using 5.7.22

I want to do this **in one query without transactions**.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give you complete advice without seeing your more of your query. But you have some choices.

You could try creating a view as follows then using it.

```
CREATE VIEW selector
    AS SELECT MAX(type_id) type_id, MAX(obj_id) obj_id
         FROM t2
        WHERE id = 1
```

It looks possible that the `t2` query returns multiple rows. This view deals with that by using `MAX()` instead of `LIMIT 1`. But if `t2.id` is a primary key, then all you need is

```
CREATE VIEW selector
    AS SELECT type_id, obj_id
         FROM t2
        WHERE id = 1
```

Then you can use the view in your query.

For example

```
SELECT id
  FROM t1
 WHERE type_id = (SELECT type_id FROM selector)
   AND obj_id <> (SELECT obj_id FROM selector)
```

Or you could figure out how to use join operations rather than subqueries.

```
SELECT id
  FROM t1
  JOIN selector ON t1.type_id = selector.type_id AND t1.obj_id <> selector.obj_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select id from t1 ,(select type_id from t2 where id=1 limit 1)  t where type_id=t.type_id and id not in  
            (select obj_id from t2
                where 
                    type_id = t.type_id 
                    and
                    type2_id = t.type_id   
                    ...
             )
```